# Populate tooltip from 2 series, that have different number of data numbers

Tags: highcharts, tooltip, time-series

`Serie 1 (Temperature)` has data points 1 per hour (in chart 1) and `Serie 2 (precipitation)` has data point 1 per day (in chart 2). The both charts have 1 `rnageselector (xAxis)`. In the tooltip the value of both series are displayed. But the value of serie 2 only when the time match. How do I get in the `tooltip` the value of Serie 2 (1/day) to each hour of the same day?

Comment: That's how shared tooltip works in Highstock: when two points have the same `x` then they are displayed in tooltip. If this doesn't work for you, disable `shared` option, then use `tooltip.formatter` to find points you want to display.

Comment: Is Y value of other X available in tooltip 
(to X[i] displaying eg Y[i-3])?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment?

Comment: When displaying the tooltip to x (which has a data point (y value) in serie 1), how do I get the Y-value of another X in series 2. Example:  X = 2014-03-01 14:00. y in serie 1 = 12. But I want to show in tooltip to this X the y value belonging to 2014-03-01 1:00 of serie 2. This value in series 2 belongs to every x in 2014-03-01. See on webpage http://www.grondwaterinhellevoetsluis.nl/Location.aspx?id=bda91f9d-a262-4287-b0c0-8f8498260361&&groep=Gemeente%20Hellevoetsluis were now only at 1:00 hour the precipitiation is displayed in the tooltip

Comment: In tooltip you have access to al lseries using `this.point.series.chart.series`. Now find series which has day-based points (probably `this.point.series.chart.series[1]`) and find proper points in series.data.